# session_start() not working and only page loading not showing any message

Tags: php, session

trying to start session using session_start() in config file which is in operation folder. now this file is getting included in index file

index.php

```
<?php require "/operation/config";  echo "hi"; ?>
```

config`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
ini_set('max_execution_time','100000');
session_start();
define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'nmiffsak_nmiff');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'nmiff');
define('DB_NAME', 'nmiffsak_nmiff');
?>`
```

now if i comment on session_start() line it ll load the page and ll show the output but i want to session to be started

AND if i put

```
<?php require "/operation/config" or die();  echo "hi"; ?>
```

then This error is there

```
Warning: require(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\nmiff\index.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\nmiff\index.php on line 3
```

Comment: @AD7six it include config.php only by mistakely i have return that it is config. and is on 1st line only error is new . pls help

Comment: it lie on line number 1 only

Comment: the error which i have post is the from the same code only..just line number is not right as i remove make it into 1 line of code...dnt bleam others if u dnt know the solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have disabled UTF-8 BOM in both files. Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at top of your config file.

Comment: thanx a lot for replay i added line of code u have gave me but it is still not working...it is showing that page is getting load..

Answer (score 0):

Give a .php-extension for your config-file, then it should work perfectly fine:

```
<?php 
require "/operation/config.php"; 
echo "hi"; 
?>
```